# Detect if user have my Chrome extension installed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I started to work on a very cool Chrome extension and I ran into a little problem.

I want to allow my user to share a link. By sharing this link, other users can get some information with my extension.

The problem is when a user click on the shared link, I want to check if my Chrome extension is installed on his browser. If it does - great, else - I want to redirect him to download my extension.

Any ideas how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the extension add an invisible element to the DOM of every page that it loads, marking it with a unique ID. When the user clicks on that link, run some javascript to check for that element -- if it doesn't exist, then you know the extension hasn't been installed.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to have your extension run a content script on all sites* and add a listener for click events on `document`. It would check `event.target` to make sure it's a link and has a particular prefix, and if it does, it would call the `preventDefault` method of its parameter and do its stuff. For users without your extension, the link would of course work like any other.

*This causes Chrome to warn your potential users about this when they install your extension; read [Permission Warnings](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to set/modify headers in the HTTP requests (as of Chrome 17?). Adding a header to requests would mean you can detect the presence of the extension on the server side.

This is fairly unintrusive. Many extensions/plugins have historically modified the User-Agent header.